# Parsing output result of "ls -l" to get user and group on QNX

Tags: shell, sed, ls, qnx

I'm using QNX.

I have the following output of `ls -l`:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root      root           4096 Jul 26  2021 bin
```

From this, I would want to use `sed` to extract the user and group, and put these strings into shell variables.

I do not have access to a `stat` command.

Comment: Don't try to [parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). Perhaps `stat` would suit your needs?

Comment: In machine don`t install stat and I don't have permission to install a new package

Comment: `stat` is a part of GNU coreutils, as is `ls`. See `whereis stat` (s/b: /usr/bin/stat)

Comment: No `stat`? Does `find / -prune -printf '%g:%u\n'` print something like `root:root`? or is there an error?

Comment: It is QNX and many simple commands don`t working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pure sed

1. gather username

   ```
   user=$(ls -ld .| sed 's/^[dlLsStT+@rwx-]*[ 0-9]*\([^ ]*\).*$/\1/')
   ```
2. gather goup name

   ```
   group=$(ls -ld .| sed -e s/$user// -e 's/^[dlLsStT+@rwx-]*[ 0-9]*\([^ ]*\).*$/\1/')
   ```

where

- first `sed` didn't need `-e` as only one command
- `^[dlLsStT+@rwx-]*[ 0-9]*` catch file access and size (you may need to add `s` for socket/ `c`,`b` for special file)
- `\([^ ]*\)` match and remember username/group name (without space in them of course)
- `.*$` rest of line
- `\1` recall first remembered pattern

Note :

- this will fail if user is `rwx` (or any combination matching access bit)
- as Stéphane Chazelas pointed out, this relay on username and group name being "normal".

Comment: The first field may also contain some `lLsStT+@` characters (but no backslash), not just `drwx-`.

Comment: Both would strip characters ranging between 0 and 9 from the start of the username. While it's not common to have user names starting with digits (or other characters ranging between 0 and 9 which generally are not ASCII ones), `ls -l` could put uids/gids there which are all numeric, when it can't resolve those ids to names.

Comment: That `sed -e s/$user//` is a bit brittle and not foolproof and not only because you forgot the quotes. What if `$user` is `rwx`, a number, or contains `/` or regexp operators?

Comment: And I have a problem, RWX can change any time

Comment: I meant that `lLsStT+@` can be part of the permissions, not the file type which for `.` should be `d`. For the type of files other than `.`, there's an even wider ranger of possible characters depending on the system.

Answer (score 5):

If your shell is a POSIX one, and user and group names don't contain space characters, you can use the split+glob operator (invoked implicitly when you leave parameter expansions, command substitution or arithmetic expansion unquoted in list contexts):

```
IFS=' ' # split on space only
set -o noglob # disable the glob part
output=$(LC_ALL=C ls -Lld bin) || exit # exit if bin can't be stat()ed.

set -- $output # split+glob $output and assign result to positional parameters

mode=$1 # could also contain +, @... to specify system-dependent extra
        # information such as the presence of ACLs or extended attributes

links=$2 user=$3 group=$4 size=$5
```

If you can't guarantee user and group names won't contain space characters, you could use `ls -n` instead of `ls -l` and you'd then get the uid and gid in `$user` and `$group` which may be enough for your needs.

With `sed`, you could use it to parse the first line of the output of `ls` and generate the shell code that sets the variables:

```
get_credentials() {
  eval "$(
    sp=' \{1,\}' nsp='[^ ]\{1,\}'
    LC_ALL=C ls -Lld -- "${1?}" |
      LC_ALL=C sed -n "
        /^$nsp$sp$nsp$sp\($nsp\)$sp\($nsp\).*$/ {
          s//\1 \2/
          s/'/'\\\\''/g
          s/\($nsp\) \($nsp\)/user='\1' group='\2' ||/p
        }
        q"
    ) false"
}
```

To be used as:

```
get_credentials bin || exit
printf 'The %s name is: "%s"\n' user  "$user" \
                                group "$group"
```

That would `eval`uate the `user='the-user' group='the-group' || false` shell code (or `user='o'\''connor'...` for `o'connor` for instance) if the user and group names can be extracted from the first line of `ls` output, or  `false` otherwise.